# Laravel 5.7 - Eager loading with morphMany relationship and custom attribute getter

Tags: php, laravel, eager-loading

So I have the following models:

```
class TemplateEntity extends Model {
    protected $table = "TemplateEntities";

    const UPDATED_AT = null;
    const CREATED_AT = null;

    public function element() {
        return $this->morphTo("element", "entity_type", "id_Entity");
    }

    public function getEntityTypeAttribute($entity_type) {
        return 'App\\' . $entity_type;
    }
}

class Template extends Model {
    protected $table = "Template";

    const UPDATED_AT = null;
    const CREATED_AT = null;

    public function entities() {
        return $this->hasMany("App\TemplateEntity", "id_Template");
    }
}

class TemplateEntity extends Model {
    protected $table = "TemplateEntities";

    const UPDATED_AT = null;
    const CREATED_AT = null;

    public function element() {
        return $this->morphTo("element", "entity_type", "id_Entity");
    }

    public function getEntityTypeAttribute($entity_type) {
        return 'App\\' . $entity_type;
    }
}
```

I want to eager load template entity elements using Eloquent ORM's ::with() method, however whenever I do this I get an error:

```
//$template_id is defined as a controller param
$template = Template::with("entities", "entities.element")->where("id", "=", $template_id)->get()

"Class 'App\' not found"
```

I did some debugging and when I echo $entity_type in TemplateEntity's GetEntityTypeAttribute() method I get an empty value. However, my models generally work fine if I don't use eager loading, but I would like to add it to my application if possible to make it more efficient.

Any help you all can provide would help!

edit: fixed a typo, should have been Template::with instead of $template::with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of the problem might be a blank class in that variable.  Suggest you use the class name when calling `get()`.  So `\App\Template::` instead of `$template::`.

Another item to help may be the way you are calling the relationship's eager load.  Perhaps try to call through the function.  This might work better for you:

```
 \App\Template::with(['entities' => function($query){
        $query->with('element');
    }])->get();
```

The accessor function might be interfering with the Laravel morph function.  I realise you want to use the shortened name of the class in the DB.  To do this without the use of the getter (and globally), I suggest using a morphMap.

In **AppServiceProvider** inside the `boot()` method:

```
  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation::morphMap([
        'MyTemplate' => \App\MyTemplate::class,  
        'Section' => \App\Section::class,  
         // etc.        
    ]);
```

This will allow you to add only 'Section' to the DB and remove the accessor function from your class.

Comment: er my bad, that was a typo on my part. even with \App\Template::with i still get an error.

Comment: And if you try the query as I wrote above do you still get the exact same error?  IE is the namespace correct, and does the internal function make a difference?

Comment: nope, still getting the same error. i think it might be a bug with laravel's getAttribute() methods, honestly

Comment: Yes, I've never seen a getter on the morphTo type before.  This is handled internally by Laravel, and might be conflicting something like the timing of the response.  I've usually seen the type as a variable on the class, stored in the db next to the morphing ID.  If it's not in the DB, this may conflict the call to find the class, which seems to be the case.  Is it possible to add the entity_type to the class/db and remove the getter?  For the addition of \App... you can use a morphmap if you like

Comment: the entity_type is stored in the db, but only as "Section" or "SectionGroup". it's missing the required "App\" to get the proper model. how do you use morphmap?